# How are featured queries selected in Data Explorer?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Recent and popular queries are self explanatory, but how are [featured queries](http://odata.stackexchange.com/serverfault/queries?order_by=featured) selected in Data Explorer?

Comment: I think a much better question is how do you think they should be selected. Having me do all the selecting is very anti-stackoverflow ethics. I would love some suggestions of a process that works better, keeping in mind the massive duplicate problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the [FAQ](http://odata.stackexchange.com/faq) they are manually selected by the admins:

> At the moment, admins have permission to feature interesting queries on this page, we are looking for better ways to manage the huge query list that is building up.