# Have a question to publish odata queries

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

**Note: This is not that question.**

> I think a much better question is how do you think they should be selected. Having me do all the selecting is very anti-stackoverflow ethics. I would love some suggestions of a process that works better, keeping in mind the massive duplicate problem. – **waffles**

[How are featured queries selected in Data Explorer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51975/how-are-featured-queries-selected-in-data-explorer)

My suggestion is to have a CW question on meta to post queries and the answers with the most votes are featured.

Comment: is it spam question ?

Comment: I somewhat like this suggestion, but my issue with it is that its totally not discoverable

Comment: @waffles: Linking to it from the data explorer might make it more discoverable.

http://i48.tinypic.com/29pu8zq.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer)?